# How to use variables (strings) with quotes and whitespace at the end inside query in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

Let say that i have the following code

```
    comm='This is/a string with (some single quotes, inside like 'F' this)'
print(df.query('Column1==@comm')['Column2'].values[0])
```

This give me an error instead of return the value of `Column2` when `comm` exist in `Column1`

I also tried:

```
df.query("Column1=='{0}'".format(comm))['Column2'].values[0]
```

Without luck as well.

If the variable is a string without single `'` or double `"` quotes, it works just fine.

In the actual code `comm` is a dynamic variable that changes and takes for values strings with single `'` and double `"` quotes in.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
It seems that pandas queries suffer from various other problems if the string contain symbols.

I tried and replaced as advised `comm.replace("'","\\'")` and worked for strings containing single quotes `'`.

Now im facing other problems where the query fail to find the string in the dataframe ( even though the string exists ) if the string contain whitespace at the end.

```
comm='This is a test. string '
comm='This is a test string/ '
```

Comment: Use `"Column1 == '@comm'"`.

Comment: If a string has single quotes inside the string, use double quotes to delimit it `"like 'this'"`, or vice versa.

Comment: Didn't work as well

Comment: The strings im using can have single and double quotes. I also tried triple single quotes for the variable but failed.

Comment: If panda query could accept triple single `'''` for the variable, there wouldn't be any problem..

But it doesn't accept.

Answer (score 0):

As I see your string contains both.

No problem:

```
comm = "string with \" and ' in it!"
```

Comment: Yeap exactly and the problem is that in actual code  `comm` is a variable that changes and takes for values strings with single `'` and double `"` quotes in.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: You can just replace every " with an \"

Comment: I found this an inconvenience. There must be a "clean" way.

Comment: This works totally fine. But if you need such a way I need to know more about the way that variable changes. Where do you get the values from, etc?

Comment: The values are taken from an sqlite database and transformed to a pandas dataframe for fast query access.

Comment: The code is what i have typed in my first post. What is dynamic is the variable that is "sensitive" data that i cant post here. 

The characteristics of that data is that they are strings that contain single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write single quotes inside single quotes string because what you actually do is separating the string into two strings leaving syntax error

```
comm='This is/a string with (some single quotes, inside like ' +  F  + ' this)'
```

F is just a variable now not part of string

This lines of code works fine

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["string with 'single' quotes,inside like 'F' this", 'Data'],
    'Column2':['Done','Data2']})
    comm="string with 'single' quotes,inside like 'F' this"
    print(df.query('Column1==@comm')['Column2'].values[0])
```

edited :-
You can use single quotes inside single quotes by write it prefixed by `\'F\'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['string with \'single\' quotes,inside like \'F\' this', 'Data'],
'Column2':['Done','Data2']})
comm='string with \'single\' quotes,inside like \'F\' this'
print(df.query('Column1==@comm')['Column2'].values[0])
```

This trick to make query work for double quotes format by changing it to format a little bit.

```
import json 
def convert_string(string): #Function which change format to be '"<string>"'
    return json.dumps(string)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['here', 'Data'],
'Column2':['Done','Data2']})
comm="here"
converted = convert_string(comm)
print(df.query('Column1=={}'.format(converted))['Column2'].values[0])
```

Better Solution is by using exception.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['here', 'Data'],
'Column2':['Done','Data2']})
comm="here"
try:
    print(df.query('Column1==@comm')['Column2'].values[0])
except:
    print(df.query("Column1==@comm")['Column2'].values[0])
```

edited - 2:

This Script for removing all symbols from data frame very fast.

```
#Create random dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

random.seed(0)

def random_String(Length=20):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.punctuation
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(Length))
data_shape = 100000
data = {'A':[random_String() for i in range(data_shape)],'B':['Here string {}'.format(i) for i in range(data_shape)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```

```
Out[1]: 
                      A              B
0  {y[}!cq'&z]`t%w,~n'i  Here string 0
1  si[g.^q)>^-~jtg?e~{<  Here string 1
2  v%*gw"u./n*%#|(qd^*a  Here string 2
3  f?`z>_];/a.&_|vp?u>|  Here string 3
4  em+op^j^)#ffu}'&gt*s  Here string 4
```

```
def remove_symbols(s): #Function remove symbols from gived column
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
def convert_data(pandas_series):
     return pandas_series.apply(remove_symbols)
df['A'] = convert_data(df['A'])
df.head()
```

```
Out[2]: 
             A              B
0     ycqztwni  Here string 0
1     sigqjtge  Here string 1
2     vgwunqda  Here string 2
3       fzavpu  Here string 3
4  emopjffugts  Here string 4
```

Comment: I will edit my post.

The problem is that in actual code `comm` is a dynamic variable that changes and takes for values strings with single `'` and double `"` quotes in

Comment: @Codeburn I edited solution if it's still not solve problem please post this part of your code

Comment: This has already been advised by  `Lukas Nießen`. But as i replied the dataframe is taken from an sqlite that i must not edit. 

So i have to create a new dataframe based on the first one where i will replace `'` with `\'` and `"` with `\"` so i can query properly the dataframe.

This feels like an inconvenience - dirty way in contrast of using triple `'''` codes for the variable for example.

I hope someone will advice something else or ill have to use this "dirty" way.

Comment: it's not needed to create a new dataframe you can just write function which convert @comm variable to desired format if you use single quotes in query write which function convert any single quotes string to double quotes

Comment: I tried the json solution and it is so slow that cant be used.

Comment: What about exception?

Comment: i editing my post. I used what was advice but now im facing problems with other symbols. 

Maybe pandas query is not so good implemented ?

Comment: I added solution.
Pandas- was almost perfectly implemented,but you are dealing with data it's very sensitive case so it's should be case sensitive like symbols,capital letters or camel case letters.So I recommend changing your data to desired format, specially if your are going to use it more than one time

Comment: Thank you for your effort but this will not work for my case.

My code is doing the following. Parsing a file search split it in strings and then searches the dataframe for matching string, if found returns a result from another column in dataframe.

So for every string ( comm variable ) i have to remove every symbol then remove every symbol from dataframe and after that compare comm with the dataframe.

Comment: You still can use this solution,for every string ( comm variable ) you call remove_symbols() function and for every dataframe you could call pandas_series() . translate method very fast.

Comment: @Codeburn what was specifically slow with the json solution? It looks like the cleanest method ;-)